# AJAX: How do I make the button submit after I press "Enter"?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Currently, I am using an  with ajax to update my mysql. Now, I have to click on the button with the mouse for it to work (I am using onclick), but how can I make it accept the "enter" button? My guess is... Enter isn't working because  isn't there. If I leave it there, my ajax just doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `<input type="submit>` instead of a `<button>` or `type="button"` and then hook into the forms' `onsubmit` event.

For example:

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="alert('Hello world!'); return false">
<input type="text" name="myText" id="myText" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The `return false` ensures that the browser doesn't actually submit a form.

Comment: As a sidenote, in this example, you don't *need* the button. Pressing enter will always work. That said, from a usability point of view, not providing a button is a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in an HTML form, then enter will submit the data. You only have to write in the onsubmit event handler to do your ajax calls.

If you're not in an HTML form, check for the key press event handler. Maybe it's what you're looking for.